# Multilevel Mediaton Model with two Mediators

Tags: multilevel-analysis, mediation

does anyone has some advice for testing a research model with two parallel mediators in multilevel data?

I know how to calculate the mediating effect with one mediating variable. However, my assumption is that there are two mediating variables (intrinsic motivation and introjected motivation).

Does anyone know on how to add a second mediating variable?

My syntax so far is:

```r
fit.totaleffect <- lmer(Y ~ X1 +(1| ID) + Xc2 + Xc3 + Xc4 + Xc5 + Xc6, data = data)
fit.mediator    <- lmer(M ~ X1 +(1| ID)  + Xc2 + Xc3 + Xc4 + Xc 5+ Xc6, data = data)
fit.dv          <- lmer(Y ~ M + X1 +(1| ID)  + Xc2 + Xc3 + Xc4 + Xc5 + Xc6, data = data)
results <- mediation::mediate(fit.mediator, fit.dv, treat='X1', mediator='M')
summary(results)
```